# Remove uneven prices from list of price

Tags: javascript, php

I have prices array like this

```
  $arr = [200,201,203,205,207,300,209,212,0,211,0,0,301,213,214];
```

Above is the list of price , where there are few uneven numbers like 0, 300, 301

I am trying to remove those odd numbers by following code

```
$fresharray = [];
foreach($arr as $lol)
{
    $diff =  $lol-$arr[$i-1];

    if($diff <-50 || $diff > 50)
    {
 
    }
    else 
    {
     $fresharray[] = $lol;
    }
   
    $i++;
}
```

I am basically comparing current number with previous number and if difference is more than 50 i am excluding it to my fresharray , but my problem is when there is two 0 like 0,0  or 300,301.. here difference is 0 and -1 and its getting added to my fresharray.How do I remove this odd numbers out of my price array.. please note my array size is usually more than 1000.Solution can be either in php or javascript.Thanks.

please note price can start from 200 and end at 400 too.. but i just wanna check around current number for which is uneven.

Comment: "_odd numbers like 0, 300, 301_" 0 and 300 are _even_ numbers

Comment: this question is very confused... I was suggesting before how to check for even/odd before finding out that you are messing up with the meaning itself of odd and even.. plus 301-300 it's 1 and not zero. Plus what you say is inconsistent with your code.

Comment: "_and its getting added to my fresharray_" Are you saying 300 and 301 are getting added to that `$fresharray`? Cannot reproduce that. What does `print_r($fresharray);` output for you?

Comment: do you mean "outliers" instead of uneven numbers? (values that are statistically significant different to the expected range, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier)

Comment: don't compare with the previous element in your `$arr`, but with the latest added element in `$fresharr`

Comment: @cyberbrain : ah thats a good idea , will check it out  , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since you say there is a price range, you should surround the inside of the foreach with an if that ignores the values that are outside your range, fixing your issue where a 0 causes the next value to get added to `$fresharray`:

```
if ($lol >= 200 && $lol <= 400)
```

The definition of "latest number" here is ambiguous. From what you said in the question, it seems you mean the previous number in $arr. For that, you just need a value that is assigned the value of `$lol` at the end of the foreach, so that the next iteration can read it.

Also, put `$fresharray[] = $lol;` inside the if rather than the else. Right now, the code adds `$lol`'s whose `$diff` is **not** <-50 or >50. This is likely why in an array that contains `[...,300,301,...]` the 301 is added to `$fresharray`.

This is the resulting code after the changes:

```
<?php
$arr = [200, 201, 203, 205, 207, 300, 209, 212, 0, 211, 0, 0, 301, 213, 214];
$fresharray = [];
$latest = $arr[0]; //Initialize $latest to avoid warnings
foreach ($arr as $lol) {
    if ($lol >= 200 && $lol <= 400) { //Ignore prices outside range
        $diff =  $lol - $latest;
        if ($diff < -50 || $diff > 50) {
            $fresharray[] = $lol;
        }
        $latest = $lol;
    }
}
```